# How do I create orthogonal basis based on two almost perpendicular vectors?

Tags: matlab, orthogonal

I am trying to create an orthogonal coordinate system based on two "almost" perpendicular vectors, which are deduced from medical images. I have two vectors, for example:

```
Z=[-1.02,1.53,-1.63];
Y=[2.39,-1.39,-2.8];
```

that are almost perpendicular, since their inner product is equal to 5e-4.

Then I find their cross product to create my 3rd basis:

```
X=cross(Y,Z);
```

Even this third vector is not completely orthogonal to `Z` and `Y`, as their inner products are in the order of -15 and -16, but I guess that is almost zero. In order to use this set of vectors as my orthogonal basis for a local coordinate system, I assume they should be almost completely perpendicular. I first thought I can do this by rounding my vectors to less decimal figures, but did not help. I guess I need to find a way to alter my initial vectors a little to make them more perpendicular, but I don't know how to do that.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_process might be helpful. You don't have to do the normalization part; basically, just subtract the projection of Y onto Z off from Z. Note that you may still not get an _exact_ zero out, because floating point numbers are like that.

Answer (score 3):

Gram-Schmidt is right as pointed out above.

Basically, you want to subtract the component of Y that is in the direction of Z from Y (Note: you can alternatively operate on Z instead of Y).

The component of Y in the Z direction is given by:

```
   dot(Y,Z)*Z/(norm(Z)^2)
```

(projection of Y onto Z)

Note that if Y is orthogonal to Z, then this is 0.

So:

```
   Y = Y - dot(Y,Z)*Z/(norm(Z)^2)
```

and Z stays unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

let V=Y+aZ
Z dot V = 0 so you can solve a and get V
Now use V and Z as you basis

You may need to normalize the vectors and use double type to get the desired precision.